# Split MySQL and compare it

Tags: mysql

I have a problem that I don't know how to resolve it, I am a begginer in SQL.

I want to display the first name of all students that have the same FirstName as the teachers name, In the database the teacher's name is a single field but contains 2 logical fields ( FirstName and LastName)

This is my database format

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,NAME VARCHAR(50)
    ,Address VARCHAR(60)
    ,YearFounded YEAR
    ,Dean VARCHAR(50)
    );

CREATE TABLE Specialty (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment
    ,IdFaculty INT (11) NOT NULL
    ,NAME VARCHAR(50)
    ,FOREIGN KEY (IdFaculty) REFERENCES Faculty(Id)
    );

CREATE TABLE Course (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment
    ,IdSpecialty INT NOT NULL
    ,NAME VARCHAR(50)
    ,TeachingYear INT
    ,Semester INT
    ,Professor VARCHAR(50)
    ,< -- TEACHER
    FOREIGN KEY (IdSpecialty) REFERENCES Specialty(Id)
    );

CREATE TABLE Student (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment
    ,< -- STUDENT
    IdFaculty INT NOT NULL
    ,IdSpecialty INT NOT NULL
    ,CurrentYear INT
    ,StudyGroup VARCHAR(10)
    ,Semester INT
    ,Scholarship VARCHAR(2)
    ,FOREIGN KEY (IdFaculty) REFERENCES Faculty(Id)
    ,FOREIGN KEY (IdSpecialty) REFERENCES Specialty(Id)
    );

CREATE TABLE StudentData (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,CNP CHAR(13)
    ,FirstName VARCHAR(30)
    ,LastName VARCHAR(30)
    ,Father VARCHAR(50)
    ,Mother VARCHAR(50)
    ,Address VARCHAR(200)
    ,Nationality VARCHAR(50)
    );

CREATE TABLE Grade (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment
    ,IdStudent INT NOT NULL
    ,IdCourse INT NOT NULL
    ,Grade INT
    ,ExamDate DATE
    ,FOREIGN KEY (IdStudent) REFERENCES Student(Id)
    ,FOREIGN KEY (IdCourse) REFERENCES Course(Id)
    );
```

Comment: StudentData has no foreign key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that `Course.Professor` field contains the professor firstname and lastname, I would use this query :

```
select sd.FirstName from StudentData sd
LEFT JOIN Student s on sd.Id = s.Id
LEFT JOIN Specialty special on s.IdSpecialty = special.Id
LEFT JOIN Course c on special.Id = c.IdSpecialty
WHERE c.Professor = CONCAT(sd.FirstName, ' ', sd.LastName)
```

**EDIT:**

If you only want students that have the same `FirstName` (not lastname) as the professor and if the professor field contains values like "Jacques Dupont" (for example) where Jacques is FirstName and Dupont is LastName then try this (using SUBSTRING_INDEX function to get the professor's FirstName):

```
select sd.FirstName from StudentData sd
LEFT JOIN Student s on sd.Id = s.Id
LEFT JOIN Specialty special on s.IdSpecialty = special.Id
LEFT JOIN Course c on special.Id = c.IdSpecialty
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.Professor,' ',1) = sd.FirstName
```